# How to catch if editor url is opened?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 8 app I select active menu item with

```
 <a class="nav-main-link {{ request()->is('admin/compilations') ? ' active_nav_menu' : '' }}"
```

and it works ok for link like :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/compilations
```

But it does not work for link like :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/compilations/2/edit
```

How can be fixed ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `is` takes patterns ... `is('admin/compilations', 'admin/compilations/*')` ... as the answer below says if you use route names you can use `routeIs(...)` that also takes patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cleanest solution for this is to gives your route names instead of hard-checking URL patterns (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes) and utilize one of the following methods:

```
$route = Route::current(); // Illuminate\Routing\Route
$name = Route::currentRouteName(); // string
$action = Route::currentRouteAction(); // string
```

If you have the `$route` instance you can also do something like `$route->currentRouteNamed(...)`

See full API here:
https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_getCurrentRoute